# Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies given @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-boot-maven-plugin, component-scan

I created a spring boot application(3.0.1). Then I connected the Postgres database and executed it. The application is up on server 8080 smoothly. then I added below-mentioned annotations.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
```

whole file,

```
package com.example.SpringRecap;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan

public class SpringRecapApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRecapApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public void Employee() {

    }


}
```

Now, below mentioned error are appeared,

```
Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies @EnableAutoConfiguration
Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies given @ComponentScan
```

Image of InteliJ:

[image: Image of InteliJ:]

If anyone knows the reason, please help me. If further information is needed to solve the problem please put a comment here.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*below mentioned error are appeared*:  This means that you can remove `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

[As the documentation on spring mentioned](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html), it is included in `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
Many Spring Boot developers like their apps to use auto-configuration, component scan and be able to define extra configuration on their "application class". A single @SpringBootApplication annotation can be used to enable those three features, that is:

    @EnableAutoConfiguration: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
    @ComponentScan: enable @Component scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)
    @Configuration: allow to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes
```

It is a check in the plugin of Intellij. Also see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177632

Comment: Yes, I can remove it, but I'm seeking a reason to appear an error. Because for some people it is working properly. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I guess it is a check in the plugin from the IDE

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177632

Comment: wow, brilliant. Thank you @Jens for the support. Now I can accept your answer.